# phalcon good practise switch between logged in interface and logged out on baseurl

Tags: phalcon

What is an good practice for switching between logged in interface and logged out interface in  Phalcon on homepage/basepage?

I can do an if-else statement to switch from interfaces in baseref/url page, but I don't think  this is an good practice to do so.

Any help is great!

Answer (score 1):

the phalcon forum uses the method you mentioned: https://github.com/phalcon/forum/blob/master/app/views/partials/top-menu.volt

A more elegant solution would be to use layouts with conditionals

Your frontend controllers can inherit from a BaseFrontendController, and choose the layout in their initialize:

```
class BaseFrontendController extends BaseController {

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize()
    if ( $this->authenticated ) {
        $this->view->setTemplateBefore('frontend-authenticated');
    } else {
        $this->view->setTemplateBefore('frontend-guest');
    }
}
```

then just extend that BaseFrontendController from any controller you have in the front:

```
class IndexController extends BaseFrontendController {

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize()
}
}
```

layout files are usually pretty short and just have a few includes. read more about them here:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#hierarchical-rendering